# Placing a Breakpoint Inside Class Implementing IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, debugging, httphandler

I cannot consistently make VS debugger stop in a breakpoint inside `ProcessRequest`() of a class implementing `IHttpHandler`.
It actually stopped once and then never did it again...
I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 10.

Here's my sample code:

MyImageHandler:

```
public class MyImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        AwDAL.AwDAL dal = new AwDAL.AwDAL();

        int id = 100;
        byte[] buffer = dal.GetProductPhotoByID(id);

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

WebForm:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/MyImageHandler.ashx" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It loads the image with no problem:

[image]

Comment: If your appdomain gets unloaded (for example when there is a crash somewhere in the pipeline that forces a reload) the debugger is attached to something that never gets called again.

Comment: Any way I could detect app domain unload?

Comment: There is an event logged so that should show up in the eventviewer. Maybe the debugger will help you if you set it to Break on every exception.

Comment: Good call on breaking at every exception... I did catch iis throwing because of some dll it couldn't find, which I fixed. At least now it runs clean with exit code 0. But still no stopping at break point...

Comment: Can you add [`Debugger.Launch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch(v=vs.110).aspx) at the start of  your ProcessRequest method. I wonder if it returns true or starts a new instance of VS....

Comment: When it does stop at break point it writes TRUE to my Output Window. When it does not stop at break point, nothing gets written to the Output Window, neither TRUE nor FALSE. It seems like IIS is "caching" the handler or something and at that point it gets detached from the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens only with Microsoft Edge, but not IE or Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop on the ProcessRequest method and the breakpoint gets loaded but you don't hit it, perhaps another handler is actually called.

There is an easy way to set multiple breakpoints in VS for all the handlers in your solution.

Go to Debug->New Breakpoint->Break at function
[image]

In the following window type the name of the method (or part of it), make sure the Use Intellisense checkbox is checked and press OK

VS will look for all methods in your solution with the same name and you can put the breakpoints on all of them at once with the All button.

[image]

If you just need to add breakpoints to all the methods of the same class to know which one is called, you can use some VS extencions that can do it for you, for example this is what you can do with Oz Code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is good information to have, so i am up voting it. I have found out ever since that the problem happens only with Microsoft Edge, but not IE or Firefox. Thank you.